# Developing a fullscreen "media player" on linux

Tags: linux, media

I'm a Windows developer and I need to develop a Linux application.
The goal is to have a fullscreen application being able to display different media types (images, videos, flash). There might be multiple media files being displayed at the same time on the screen (if the screen is split in multiple zones).

Can someone point me in the right direction as to what is the most appropriate technology/tools/frameworks to use?

I have experience with C#, C++ and Objective C.

Thanks,

Pyt

Answer (score 3):

You could look into [MPlayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/)'s libraries, that are [extensively used by several Linux applications](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/projects.html) as a backend.

Best of all, its cross OS and of high quality.

Answer (score 1):

Qt for the gui
Probably C++ for the code

Answer (score 0):

You could look at FFMPEG libraries (http://ffmpeg.org/index.html)
QtMediaHub (http://qt-project.org/wiki/QtMediaHub) has some useful (and pretty stable) classes and sample implementations.